# How can I make the watchpoints in eclipse show the values of my variables?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to see the values of strings and other variables when debugging Java in Eclipse.

How can I view the values of strings and other variables in my Java program?

I'm using Eclipse's debugger. My watchpoints are blank; no variable values are visible, but i'd expect them to be.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You might want to *add a little more information* to your question. Preferably a screenshot of what you're seeing and what you're expecting instead. (New users can't post images, just drop me the link!)

Comment: Why on earth 2 downvotes, the question is pretty clear by the way. A link to a screenshot may still help.  Perhaps you should try stackoverflow / this question should be migrated there since Eclipse is a programming IDE.  Have you put breakpoints in?

Comment: also, does this help answer it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378993/cant-get-eclipse-watch-points-to-work

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I think adding a breakpoint got it to show values.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a breakpoint allows you to see the values in the watchpoints.

Comment: Since the OP hadn't posted the answer and they like answers to be posted, i've post it, and the answer is within my comment as you saw..(Adding a breakpoint allows you to see the values in the watchpoints). Your question was very clear, I understood it.

Comment: Generally though for programming questions, stackoverflow is the place.. sometimes you can try them on here when there's an overlap, as perhaps here, but you get a large proportion of lower calibre responses/comments. Sometimes people will say "your question isn't clear", (in this case you were clear), and if you had asked in stackoverflow, they'd have understood it.